# Save numpy ndarray into a txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` object which I wish to save it on a txt file. The object has dimensions (shape) `(130, 118, 118)` and size `1810120`.

When I try to use `np.savetxt(f, object, delimiter=' ', fmt='1.10f')` with `f = open('test.txt', 'wb')` I receive the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\G****\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1139, in savetxt
    raise error
ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  1.10f
```

I tried various combinations of 1. f but none has worked. Suggestions anyone?

**UPDATE:** 
After following the suggestions from comments bellow, and adding `fmt='%1.10f'`
I received this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\G****\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1158, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\G****\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1162, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int8') and format specifier ('%1.10f...... the '%1.10f goes on for quite a while)
```

Comment: try: `fmt='%1.10f'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `%`, e.g. use `fmt='%1.10f'`. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Update:

```
import numpy as np

obj = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4, 5), dtype=np.int8)  # example array

with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, np.column_stack(obj), fmt='%1.10f')
```

Notice the `np.column_stack(obj)` in the last line and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25461519/6009280) to find out why it is used here. If your numpy array contains integers, you might want to use `fmt='%s'`, though. Also, `np.row_stack(obj)` might be a useful alternative, depending on what the file should look like.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please check my edited answer again?

Comment: Are the elements of your numpy array 8-bit integers?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Does that mean that I cannot save them?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372829/numpy-savetxt-resulting-a-formatting-mismatch-error-in-python-3-5).

Comment: Didn't really help unfortunately. I tried: 
`with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f: 
    np.savetxt(f, object, fmt='%.10f')` but I get the same error

Comment: `savetxt` is designed to work with 2d arrays, something with 'rows' and 'columns'.  You need `reshape` or some version of `concatenate` to turn the 3d array into a 2d one.